# に - same meaning as として?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

Could somebody please give me a hint about the meaning of に in 「反抗的な態度**に**映ったのか、隊長は舌打ちして前を向く。」. If I'm understanding correctly, に here has the same meaning as として.

```
 内容・状態などを示す。「ーとして」の意。「ほうびにもらう」
```

Some sort of translation:

> Maybe he took it (Luis's laugh) as a rebellious attitude, the captain tutted, facing forward again.

With context:

> 隊長「おい、うるさいぞ。ふざけるな」
>
> 助手席からの苛立たしげな声が、俺たちをぴしゃりと打つ。
>
> こちら隊長様だ。
>
> 瑚太朗「すみません」
>
> ルイス「ごめんなさーい」
>
> 反抗的な態度に映ったのか、隊長は舌打ちして前を向く。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

○
(～が) 反抗的な態度に見える
(～が) 反抗的な態度に映る
(～を) 反抗的な態度として受け止める
(～が) 反抗的な態度として受け止られる(受け止められる)
(～を) 反抗的な態度と捉える

x
反抗的な態度として見える(映る)
反抗的な態度に受け止める

「に」and「として」have nearly same meaning but 「に」is correct here.

Comment: Your last sentence is incorrect, or at least highly misleading.  People say 「～～として送る」、「～～として見える」、「～～として書く」, etc. all the time.

Comment: @非回答者 Thank you for your comment. I deleted the last sentence. Some people say「～～と見える」but they are (acceptable but) incorrect, and we don't use 「～～として見える」.　(「～～したとみえて」is used sometimes but they are not same.)

Comment: @非回答者 (Maybe) many of Japanese feel 「として」in 「～～として受け止める」 and 「～～として送る」are differtent. Former one can be replaced with「～～のように(見える)」but not with 「～～の替わりに」. Latter one can be replaced with 「～～の替わりに送る」but not with 「～～のように」. Same sound, same spelling but not same usage.